# How can I change foreground color of cell value in DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a grid with `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and I am trying to change the foreground color of the cell (not in edit state).

I know that I can workaround this using `DataGridTemplateColumn` but I'd like to try this.

Compare:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Is Active" 
  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding IsActive}"
  EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
  ItemsSource="{StaticResource BooleanValues}">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

and

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IsActive">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsActive}" 
        Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=combo}">
        <ComboBox Name="combo"               
          SelectedValue="{Binding IsActive}"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource BooleanValues}" />
       </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 2):

You can define your DataGridComboBoxColumn CellStyle :

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Is Active" 
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding IsActive}"
                        EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                        ItemsSource="{StaticResource BooleanValues}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, the style is applied on DataGridCell, but the text being displayed is text of TextBlock element 4 levels deeper - `DataGridCell`-`Border`-`ContentPresenter`-`TextBlockComboBox`-`ContentPresenter`-`TextBlock`.

Comment: Strange, I thought it was working in my case (as seen on the screenshot). I'll have a look as soon as possible.